# how to use angular subscribe function?

Tags: angular, typescript

I created a service in angular named UserService, and a function in app.componenet.ts that invites it.
Here is the code in the UserServer:

```
//login function in the UserService – gets user's id and returns his name
Login(userId: string):Observable<string>
  {
    let headers=new Headers({'Content-type':'application/json;charset=utf-8'});
    return this.http.get<string>(`${this.url}/login/${userId}`);
  }
```

and this is the function in the app.componenet.ts:

```
 Login()
 {
  this.userService.Login(this.userID).subscribe(n=>{
    alert('your name is'+n)
  });
 }
```

The problem is that the Login function in the componenet doesn't enter the subscribe function. It enters the Login function in the Service but not to the subscribe.
What should I do?

I followed the code with debugger and didnt see anything strange

Comment: Most probably you got an error response from http get. Besides that, it would work like you expect.

Comment: your `headers` are unused.

Comment: So how can I fix it? (the headers)

Comment: I don't know, you didnt even provide what is the console output [ask]

Comment: the console output is 'HttpErrorRespone'

Comment: Great, and dont you think that actual error content could explain what is wrong? You got http error like I wrote in before so it will not get into the `next` part of your subscriber method.

Comment: but I followed it and it enteres the function in the c# controller and got the real answer! it just stuck in the subscribe method

Comment: Dude, its like asking me what color is in the picture putting a blindfolds on my eyes at the same time. You are not showing here anything meaningfull and still you think that somehow my crystal ball will tell me what is wrong on your environment. That I will know that your backend works, I know what is exaclty the error and somehow how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Login(userId):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/login/${userId}`);

}
```

on your app component

```
Login(){
   this.userService.Login(this.userID).subscribe(n=>{
       alert('your name is'+n)
   });
}
```

if you have no other problems in your code it should work

in case it doesn't work you can do a try catch and show us the error

```
Login(){
   try{
      this.userService.Login(this.userID).subscribe(n=>{
         alert('your name is'+n)
      });
   }catch(error) console.log(error)
   
}
```

Comment: thanks but in the first option it still didnt work, in the second option it wrote httpError response

Comment: I think there is no 'first option' as those are 3 parts of "one option"

Comment: show us all the mistakes

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an issue with the code in itself.
[Here's a simple implementation using a subscribe with a get method](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-81hlfm?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

According to your comments, the error probably lies in the response from the server